# how to validate Request.QueryString.Keys.Count null value in conditon?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have included this `if (Request.QueryString.Keys.Count == 0)` condition in the page load event. In some scenarios it throws `Index was outside the bounds of the array` exeception. How to handle this exception?

Comment: That code will never throw such error. Please post your code that throws that error and we'll help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if(Request.QueryString != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Request.QueryString == null || Request.QueryString.Keys.Count == 0)
{
    // No query string parameters - do stuff....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if (Request.QueryString!=null && Request.QueryString.Keys.Count == 0)
{
     //Some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to count the NameValue pairs in the QueryString, like this:

```
if(Request.QueryString.Count==0)
```

instead of counting the keys.